# PHP 7.2 / MySQL Issue after upgrading to 18.04

Tags: upgrade, mysql, curl, php7, 18.04

After upgrading my servers to Ubuntu 18.04 I had a few issues.

- PHP pages were displayed as plain text, exposing code.
- Could not connect to MySQL from web pages using PHP (once the PHP issue was fixed), however could connect via the command line.
- On one server, PHP curl functions stopped working.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver upgrades PHP to version 7.2, but does not always seem to update the modules.  I've had the same issue in previous upgrades.

In my case, `libapache2-mod-php7.2` was missing, so to fix that problem:

```
sudo apt install php7.2 php7.2-common php7.2-cli
sudo a2enmod php7.2
```

The issue of not being able to connect to mysql was resolved with:

```
apt install php7.2-mysql
```

And the issue of missing curl functionality was resolved with:

```
apt install php7.2-curl
```